# I need override a model in third party extension

Tags: overrides, xml

I'm doing this to override the model in other extension, but doesnt works

```
    <global>
    <modules>
        <!--<sitemap_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <cms_page>CT_OverwriteXml_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Cms_Page</cms_page>
            </rewrite>
        </sitemap_resource>-->
        <aw_blog>
            <rewrite>
                <sitemap>CT_OverwriteXml_Model_Sitemap</sitemap>
            </rewrite>
        </aw_blog>
    </modules>
</global>
```

The other extension have something like this

```
...
            <sitemap>
                <rewrite>
                    <sitemap>AW_Blog_Model_Sitemap</sitemap>
                </rewrite>
            </sitemap>
        </models>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/etc/modules/CT_OverwriteXml.xml`, specify the `<depends`> node as follows:

```
    [...]
    <depends>
        <Aw_Blog />
    </depends>
    [...]
```

This will ensure your module gets loaded after the AW_Blog module.

Answer (score 0):

If your snippet from `config.xml` of your extension is accurate, it looks like you have written `<modules>` where you meant to write `<models>`. Could that be the problem?